# Changing submit button placeholder doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, forms

```css
    .RegisterForm {
        height: 35em;
        width: 25em;
    }
    
    .LoginForm {
        height: 20em;
        width: 25em;
    }
    
    .RegisterForm,
    .LoginForm {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        border-radius: 12.5%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    
    .RegisterForm h2,
    .LoginForm h2 {
        color: white;
        margin: 1em 1em 1em 5.5em;
    }
    
    .RegisterForm .Inputbox,
    .LoginForm .Inputbox {
        position: relative;
        margin: 1em;
        color: white;
        background: transparent;
    }
    
    .RegisterForm .Inputbox input,
    .LoginForm .Inputbox input {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        padding: 1em 0;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
        background: transparent;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    
    .RegisterForm .Inputbox label,
    .LoginForm .Inputbox label {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 1em 0;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #ffffff;
        transition: 0.5s;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .RegisterForm .Inputbox input:focus~label,
    .RegisterForm .Inputbox input:valid~label,
    .LoginForm .Inputbox input:focus~label,
    .LoginForm .Inputbox input:valid~label {
        top: -1em;
        left: 0;
        color: #03a9f4;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }
    
    .RegisterForm input[Type="submit"],
    .LoginForm input[Type="submit"] {
        margin: 1em 1em 1em 1.5em;
        padding: 0.5em 1.2em;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        background: #03a9f4;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<form action="../php/Inloggen.php" method="post" class="LoginForm">
    <!-- Titel -->
    <h2>Inloggen</h2>

    <!-- User Data -->
    <div class="Inputbox">
      <input type="email" name="Email" required>
      <label for=" Email ">Email</label>
    </div>

    <div class="Inputbox">
      <input type="password" name="Password" required>
      <label for="Password ">Wachtwoord</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Send form -->
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" palceholder="Inloggen">
</form>
```

I have a submit button: `<input type="submit" name="Submit" palceholder="Inloggen">`
the placeholder says "inloggen". so it should show inloggen at the button, right?

it doesnt. it shows "verzenden" which I have at a different html page. when i use inspect element the button placeholder shows "inloggen"
[image: Button in the browser not showing inloggen]

I thought it was a a caching issue, so I restarted the browser but it didnt help.

Comment: The `for` attribute on a `<label>` associates it using the `id` of the form control, not the `name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the placeholder says "inloggen". so it should show inloggen at the button, right?

No.

Placeholders are there to provide a hint (usually an example) for what someone can type into an input. You can't type anything into a submit button, so it doesn't make sense for it to do anything.

The display text for an `<input type="submit">` is specified by the **`value`** attribute.

If you want to have different display text and submitted value, use a `<button>` element:

```
<button name="field_name" value="submitted_value">Display Text</button>
```